# How do I finish code for search form that displays files in a folder?

Tags: php, html, search

I am wanting a search form that searches and displays files in a folder. I have found the reference php code below (which I am completely unfamiliar with):

```
<?php
$dir = "/Users/rosaliaobrien/Desktop/Bio_pages/HTML_files/South";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if($file == $_???['_???']){
            echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
}
?>
```

I am not sure what to plug in for the two spaces labeled '_???'. Here is the html code for the search bar:

```
<form class="searchbar" action="//Desktop/fields/html\ codes/searchresults.php" style="max-width:300px">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code,
if you have files like abchome.txt then on searching home, it will display the abchome.txt file, so partial matching of file names is enabled.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['submit'])){
    $search = trim($_GET['search']);
    $dir = "/Users/rosaliaobrien/Desktop/Bio_pages/HTML_files/South";
    // $dir = "/usr/games/";

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                // here u can use regular expressions also
                if(strpos($file, $search) !== false){
                    echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."<br/>");
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
?>


<form class="searchbar" action="" style="max-width:300px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Should it be displaying my results? Not sure if I need to code something separate to display results or if it does it automatically.

Comment: It will display result but not so nicely...you need to add some html & css.